# Play JSON JsPath Conditional Types

Tags: scala, playframework, deserialization, play-json

I receive JSON response from an upstream server that I do not have a control on, for modification.

The JSON could have the following format

```
{"data":[["Some_text","boolean",["key_string1","key_string2"]]]}
```

Or it could also show up as

```
{"data":[["Some_text","boolean","key_string2"]]}
```

Or it could show up as a combination of the two.

```
{"data":[["Some_text","boolean",["key_string1","key_string2"]],["Some_text","boolean","key_string2"]]}
```

Individually I can define the READS for each format if they don't mix. 
However, given that the data may be of mixed format, I am unable to wrap my head around how the Reads should be written so as to check if the underlying type is a string or array before transforming it?

Is it possible to say something like

```
  (
    (JsPath)(0).read[String] and
    (JsPath)(1).read[Boolean] and
    (JsPath)(2).read( **if type is simple, String OR if type is array, then seq** )
  )(SomeGloriousCaseClass)
```

How can I approach this problem of deserializing?

Comment: I have a pretty good idea of how to do it but could you link the underlying class you want it to be mapped to ?

Comment: Sure thing, I don't mind any format for the underlying class, if it solves the problem regarding deserializing. Currently I was using the following case class `case class SomeGloriousCaseClass(initialPart: String, booleanPart: Boolean, theDifficultPart: Seq[String])`. I don't even mind if everything gets converted into a sequence

Comment: `(_ \ "data").read[JsArray].flatMap { jsa => ??? }`

Comment: as @cchantep replied, you should be able to read it as a `JsValue` and then it's up to you to write a function that given a `JsValue`, return a `Seq[String]`. I am thinking of a recursive method which match on the value, and if the value is a string concatenate it to the final seq if it is an array recurse over it. You might be able to do this with a `foldLeft` method

Comment: Better to read as `JsArray`, that's an easy first validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fun I implemented a solution. You might need to tweak it a bit :

```
private def toSeq(jsValue: JsValue): JsResult[Seq[String]] = {
    jsValue match {
      case JsArray(es:Seq[JsValue]) ⇒ sequence(es.map(e ⇒ toSeq(jsValue))).map(_.flatten)
      case JsString(s) ⇒ JsSuccess(s :: Nil)
      case _ ⇒ JsError("INVALID")
    }
  }

  private def sequence[A](seq:Seq[JsResult[A]]):JsResult[Seq[A]] = {
    seq.foldLeft(JsResult.applicativeJsResult.pure(Seq[A]()))((acc, next) ⇒ for(acc2 ← acc; next2 ← next) yield acc2 :+ next2)
  }
```

Hope it helps and would be glad to provide further explanations if needed.

Comment: As a side note I would like to mention that I reimplemented `sequence` because I have no idea if there is one existing

Comment: Although this is not what I finally used, this did help me in figuring out how to solve the problem. Thanks Louis!